# Finding complex conjugate

Tags: complex

I have some expressions and I would like to calculate the complex conjugate of them. How can I get `delta2` and `delta3` in a simple $a+ib$ form?

The code I have is

```
rhobar = 200
omega = 100
xi = 1000
phi = 200
xibar = 2000
x3 = 20

gamma1 = .5*(-i*xibar^.5*omega - xi*xibar^-.5)
gamma2 = .5*(i*xi*(xibar/rhobar)^.5 + xibar^-.5*phi)
gamma3 = .5*(-i*omega*xibar^.5 - xi*xibar^-.5)
gamma4 = .5*(-xibar^-.5*phi - i*xi*(xibar^.5/rhobar))

delta2 = i*xibar^.5*gamma1*e^(2*i*xi*x3) + rhobar*xibar^-.5*gamma2*e^(2*i*xi*x3)
delta3 = rhobar*xibar^.5*gamma4*e^(-2*i*xi*x3) - i*xibar^.5*gamma3*e^(-2*i*xi*x3)
```

I would like to know if $\Delta_2 = \bar \Delta_3.$

Comment: Have a look at `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: There's a syntax error, unbalanced `()` in your definition of `gamma4`.

Comment: You appear to be using `i` (an undefined symbol) where you intend `I`.

Comment: Also, you're using `e` where I think you intended `E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant `I` when you used `i` and `E` when you used `e`, there are no free variables in `delta2` and `delta3`, so they evaluate to numbers. With an extra `)` on the end of the `gamma4` expression (maybe not where it belongs):

```
delta2==Conjugate[delta3]
(* False *)
```

It might be better in the future to use the exact `1/2` in place of the inexact `.5`, avoiding numerical round-off error.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, this has helped me greatly. I'm a beginner!